# Is there a PostgreSQL equivalent of SQL Server profiler?

Tags: postgresql, profiler

I need to see the queries submitted to a PostgreSQL server.  Normally I would use SQL Server profiler to perform this action in SQL Server land, but I'm yet to find how to do this in PostgreSQL.  There appears to be quite a few pay-for tools, I am hoping there is an open source variant.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can use the log_statement config setting to get the list of all the queries to a server

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#guc-log-statement

Just set that, and the logging file path and you'll have the list.  You can also configure it to only log long running queries.

You can then take those queries and run EXPLAIN on them to find out what's going on with them.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/using-explain.html

Comment: perfect, threw a tail -f against it

Comment: Well, its hard to call .csv log files an "equivalent of SQL Server profiler"...

Answer (score 42):

Adding to Joshua's answer, to see [which queries are currently running](https://web.archive.org/web/20200110143058/http://chrismiles.info/systemsadmin/databases/articles/viewing-current-postgresql-queries/) simply issue the following statement at any time (e.g. in PGAdminIII's query window):

```
SELECT datname,procpid,current_query FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

Sample output:

```
     datname    | procpid | current_query
 ---------------+---------+---------------
  mydatabaseabc |    2587 | <IDLE>
  anotherdb     |   15726 | SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=123 ;
  mydatabaseabc |   15851 | <IDLE>
 (3 rows)
```

Comment: With my version of PG (9.3), I used the following query: SELECT datname, pid, usename, application_name, client_addr, query
  FROM pg_stat_activity;  pg_stat_activity is a view of the DB 'postgresql'

Comment: SELECT client_addr, state_change, query FROM pg_stat_activity;

Comment: The "query" column length is too short to display long queries.

Answer (score 35):

I discovered pgBadger (https://pgbadger.darold.net/) and it is a fantastic tool that saved my life many times. Here is an example of an
[report](https://pgbadger.darold.net/examples/sample.html).
If you open it and go to 'top' menu you can see the slowest queries and the time consuming queries.
Then you can ask details and see nice graphs that show you the queries by hour and if you use detail button you can see the SQL text in a pretty form. So I can see that this tool is free and perfect.

Comment: Pretty nice tool. I used this tutorial to install it, as the official doc is pretty verbose: https://www.dhis2.org/analysing-postgresql-logs-using-pgbadger

Comment: Just a note, that the tool is for *nix systems only, which sucks for Windows users

Comment: +1 as the OP asked for a tool like Sql Server Profiler not config options to manually extract needed performance info.

Comment: Easy to install and easy to use! `sudo apt install pgbadger`  `pgbadger /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log` Thanks for the recommendation! It's the profiler tool I was looking for. https://github.com/darold/pgbadger#postgresql-configuration

Comment: @EAmez you can run pgBadger on windows. See: https://github.com/darold/pgbadger/issues/480

Comment: @Flimtix, not sure if your answer is for me: I wasn't asking por pgBadger on Windows (I already use it on Linux). I added a comment to explain why this answer should be upvoted and this is because the OP was asking for tools, not configurations (though config changes should be made in order to use pgBadger).

Comment: dhis2.org archived link https://web.archive.org/web/20200729092607/dhis2.org/analysing-postgresql-logs-using-pgbadger

Answer (score 29):

> I need to see the queries submitted to a PostgreSQL server

As an option, if you use pgAdmin (on my picture it's pgAdmin 4 v2.1). You can observe queries via "Dashboard" tab:
[image: pgadmin4 query from application, dashboard]

**Update on Jun, 2022. Answering to the questions in the comments.**

**Question 1:** My long SQL query gets truncated, is there any workaround?

Follow steps below:

1. Close pgAdmin
2. Find `postgresql.conf` file. On my computer it is located in `c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\data\postgresql.conf`. If you can't find it - read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602450/where-does-postgresql-store-configuration-conf-files) for more details.
3. Open `postgresql.conf` file and find property called `track_activity_query_size`. As you see by default the value is 1024 that means - all queries bigger than 1024 symbols will be truncated. Uncomment this property and set a new value, for example:

   ```
   track_activity_query_size = 32768
   ```
4. Restart PostgreSQL service on your computer
5. P.S: now everything is ready, but keep in mind that this change can slightly decrease the performance. From development/debugging standpoint you won't see any difference, but better don't forget to revert this property in 'production' environment. For more details read [this article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/fixing-track_activity_query_size-in-postgresql-conf/).

**Question 2:** I ran my function/method that triggers SQL query but I still can't see it in pgAdmin, or sometimes I see it but it runs so quickly so I can't even expand the session on 'Dashboard' tab?

Answer: Try to run your application in 'debug' mode and set a breakpoint right before you close the connection to the database. At the same time (while you debugging) click on 'refresh' button on 'Dashboard' tab in pgAdmin.

Comment: This can't show long SQL statements. The SQL gets truncated.

Comment: And it also can't show short running queries. Is there a way to see queries that has just finished?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [pg_stat_statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/pgstatstatements.html) extension.

If running the db in docker just add this command in `docker-compose.yml`, otherwise just look at the installation instructions for your setup:

```
command: postgres -c shared_preload_libraries=pg_stat_statements -c pg_stat_statements.track=all -c max_connections=200
```

And then in the db run this query:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_stat_statements;
```

Now to see the operations that took more time run:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_statements ORDER BY total_time/calls DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Or play with other queries over that view to find what you are looking for.

Comment: Also similarly, SELECT query_start,query,datname FROM pg_stat_activity where datname='your database name' order by query_start desc

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28147037/pghero-on-postgresapp-pg-stat-statements-must-be-loaded-via-shared-preload-libra

Answer (score 2):

All those tools like pgbadger or pg_stat_statements require access to the server, and/or altering the server-settings/[server-log-settings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#guc-log-statement), which is not such a good idea, especially if it requires server-restart and because logging slows everything down, including production use.

In addition to that, extensions such as pg_stat_statements don't really show the queries, let alone in chronological order, and pg_stat_activity doesn't show you anything that doesn't run right now, and in addition, queries that are running that are from other users than you.

Instead of running any such crap, you can add a TCP-proxy in between your application and PostgreSQL-server.

Then your TCP-proxy reads all the sql-query-statements from what goes over the wire from your application to the server, and outputs it to console (or wherever). Also it forwards everything to PostgreSQL and returns the answer(s) to your application.

This way, you **don't** need to stop/start/restart your db-server, you **don't** need admin/root rights **!ON THE DB-SERVER!** to change the config file, and you **don't** need any access to the db-server. All you need to do is change the db connection string in your application (e.g. in your dev-environment) to point to the proxy server instead of the sql-server (the proxy-server then needs to point to the sql-server). Then you can see (in chronological order) what your <insert_profanity_here> application does on the database - and also, other people's queries don't show up (which makes it even better than sql-server-profiler). [Of course, you can also see what other people do if you put it on the db server on the old db port, and assing the db a new port. ]

I have implemented this with **[pg_proxy_net](https://github.com/ststeiger/pg_proxy_net)** 
(runs on Windows, Linux and Mac and doesn't require OS-dependencies, as it is .NET-Core-self-contained-deployment).

That way, you get appx. "the same" as you get with sql-server profiler. 
Wait, if you aren't disturbed by other people's queries, what you get with pg_proxy_net is actually better than what you get with sql-server profiler.

Also, on github, I have a [command-line MS-SQL-Server profiler that works on Linux/Mac](https://github.com/ststeiger/sql_profiler).
And an [GUI MS-SQL-Express-Profiler for Windows](https://github.com/ststeiger/ExpressProfiler).

The funny thing is, once you have written one such tool, writing some more is just a piece of cake and done in under a day.

Also, if you want to get pg_stat_statements to work, you need to alter the config file (postgresql.conf), adding tracking and preloading libraries, **and then restart the server**:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_stat_statements;

-- D:\Programme\LessPortableApps\SQL_PostGreSQL\PostgreSQLPortable\Data\data\postgresql.conf

shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements'
pg_stat_statements.track = all
```

You find the documentation for the PostgreSQL protocol here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-overview.html

You can see how the data is written into the TCP-buffer by looking at the source code of a postgresql-client, e.g. FrontendMessages of Npgsql on github:
https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/main/src/Npgsql/Internal/NpgsqlConnector.FrontendMessages.cs

Also, just in case you have a .NET application (with source code) that uses Npgsql, you might want to have a look at Npgsql.OpenTelemetry.

PS: 
To configure the logs, see [ChartIO Tutorial](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-log-queries-in-postgresql/) and [TablePlus](https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/10/how-to-show-queries-log-in-postgresql.html).

Cheers ! 
Happy "profiling" !

[image: PG Profiled]

Comment: dotnetcore! awesome