# Where does PostgreSQL store configuration/conf files?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, configuration

I have recently installed PostgreSQL on Ubuntu with the EnterpriseDB package. I can connect to the database locally, but I can't configure it because I can't find config files. I searched through entire hard drive and found only samples like `pg_hba.conf.sample`

Where are the PostgreSQL `.conf` files?

Comment: In case you are looking for sql's start-up file, it is called `.psqlrc` and you can open it with a text editor in your terminal.

Comment: @Sajeev The OP asked about the config file locations on Ubuntu. Your answer refers to Windows.

Answer (score 1248, accepted):

Or ask your database:

```
$ psql -U postgres -c 'SHOW config_file'
```

or, if logged in as the `ubuntu` user:

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql -c 'SHOW config_file'
```

Comment: they are in data directory... default user can't get there thus I couldn't find them.

Comment: That's the default location, but you can change this when you start PostgreSQL. See pg_clt -D, check http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-pg-ctl.html

Comment: And if you don't know, you can access the command line utility via $YOUR_PG_INSTALL_DIR/pgsql/bin/psql

Comment: /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf

Comment: Note that you need to be logged as a postgresql superuser (e.g. `sudo -u postgres psql`).

Comment: So, in order to access this directory(var/lib/pgsql/data) the only way is to try it with user postgres or root?

Comment: On windows, my `postgres.conf` is also with my data.  I installed data & app on separate physical disks.  `SHOW config_file;` for me points to `data_install_path/postgres_version/postgresql.conf` or `D:/PostgreSQL_data/8.3/postgresql.conf`

Comment: Similarly, you can do `SHOW hba_file;` for the `pg_hba.conf` file.

Comment: NOTE `;` is really important

Comment: Usually the reason why someone wants to know this is because the server isn't working, in which case, psql returns a useless error like `psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory`

Comment: In CentOS 8 it is /var/lib/pgsql/data/

Comment: `sudo -u postgres psql -c 'SHOW config_file'` worked for me instead, in psql 10, or like  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13040860/9033534  suggests, just sign in and type `postgres=# SHOW config_file;`

Comment: I can't get the psql command to run (big imposter here, ha). But this command is just running the SQL query at the end, so alternatively you can use your favorite way of running SQL queries to do this.

Comment: Where can i find then in cpanel?

Answer (score 131):

`Ubuntu 13.04` installed using software centre :

The location for mine is:

```
/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf
```

Comment: `/etc/postgresql/9.4/main` for me.

Comment: /usr/local/var/postgresql@11 for me (MacOS)

Answer (score 90):

### Where are my postgres *.conf files?

Query the database with the sql query:

```
SHOW config_file;
```

The reason you may have trouble finding `postgresql.conf` is because it is owned by postgres, not root.

Here is where mine is on Fedora 17:

```
[root@defiant /]# ll /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf
```

Notice it is owned by **postgres**:

```
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 19332 Oct 14 09:38 
     /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf
```

It has permission 600 which explains why you have a hard time finding it with a file search.  The location of `postgresql.conf` will be different depending on what operating system you are using.

Here is the contents of mine:

```
# -----------------------------
# PostgreSQL configuration file
# -----------------------------
#
# This file consists of lines of the form:
#
#   name = value
#
# (The "=" is optional.)  Whitespace may be used.  Comments are introduced with
# "#" anywhere on a line.  The complete list of parameter names and allowed
# values can be found in the PostgreSQL documentation.
#
# The commented-out settings shown in this file represent the default values.
# Re-commenting a setting is NOT sufficient to revert it to the default value;
# you need to reload the server.
#
# This file is read on server startup and when the server receives a SIGHUP
# signal.  If you edit the file on a running system, you have to SIGHUP the
# server for the changes to take effect, or use "pg_ctl reload".  Some
# parameters, which are marked below, require a server shutdown and restart to
# take effect.
#
# Any parameter can also be given as a command-line option to the server, e.g.,
# "postgres -c log_connections=on".  Some parameters can be changed at run time
# with the "SET" SQL command.
#
# Memory units:  kB = kilobytes        Time units:  ms  = milliseconds
#                MB = megabytes                     s   = seconds
#                GB = gigabytes                     min = minutes
#                                                   h   = hours
#                                                   d   = days


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# FILE LOCATIONS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# The default values of these variables are driven from the -D command-line
# option or PGDATA environment variable, represented here as ConfigDir.

#data_directory = 'ConfigDir'       # use data in another directory
                    # (change requires restart)
#hba_file = 'ConfigDir/pg_hba.conf' # host-based authentication file
                    # (change requires restart)
#ident_file = 'ConfigDir/pg_ident.conf' # ident configuration file
                    # (change requires restart)

# If external_pid_file is not explicitly set, no extra PID file is written.
#external_pid_file = '(none)'       # write an extra PID file
                    # (change requires restart)


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

#listen_addresses = 'localhost'     # what IP address(es) to listen on;

                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                    # defaults to 'localhost', '*' = all
                    # (change requires restart)
#port = 5432                # (change requires restart)
# Note: In RHEL/Fedora installations, you can't set the port number here;
# adjust it in the service file instead.
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
# Note:  Increasing max_connections costs ~400 bytes of shared memory per
# connection slot, plus lock space (see max_locks_per_transaction).
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3 # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql, /tmp'  
    # comma-separated list of directories
                    # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''         # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777     # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour = off              # advertise server via Bonjour
                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour_name = ''          # defaults to the computer name
                    # (change requires restart)

# - Security and Authentication -

#authentication_timeout = 1min      # 1s-600s
#ssl = off              # (change requires restart)
#ssl_ciphers = 'ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH'  # allowed SSL ciphers
                    # (change requires restart)
#ssl_renegotiation_limit = 512MB    # amount of data between renegotiations
#password_encryption = on
#db_user_namespace = off

# Kerberos and GSSAPI
#krb_server_keyfile = ''
#krb_srvname = 'postgres'       # (Kerberos only)
#krb_caseins_users = off

# - TCP Keepalives -
# see "man 7 tcp" for details

#tcp_keepalives_idle = 0        # TCP_KEEPIDLE, in seconds;
                    # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_keepalives_interval = 0        # TCP_KEEPINTVL, in seconds;
                    # 0 selects the system default
#tcp_keepalives_count = 0       # TCP_KEEPCNT;
                    # 0 selects the system default


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# RESOURCE USAGE (except WAL)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Memory -

shared_buffers = 24MB           # min 128kB
                    # (change requires restart)
#temp_buffers = 8MB         # min 800kB
#max_prepared_transactions = 0      # zero disables the feature
                    # (change requires restart)
# Note:  Increasing max_prepared_transactions costs ~600 bytes of shared memory
# per transaction slot, plus lock space (see max_locks_per_transaction).
# It is not advisable to set max_prepared_transactions nonzero unless you
# actively intend to use prepared transactions.
#work_mem = 1MB             # min 64kB
#maintenance_work_mem = 16MB        # min 1MB
#max_stack_depth = 2MB          # min 100kB

# - Kernel Resource Usage -

#max_files_per_process = 1000       # min 25
                    # (change requires restart)
#shared_preload_libraries = ''      # (change requires restart)

# - Cost-Based Vacuum Delay -

#vacuum_cost_delay = 0ms        # 0-100 milliseconds
#vacuum_cost_page_hit = 1       # 0-10000 credits
#vacuum_cost_page_miss = 10     # 0-10000 credits
#vacuum_cost_page_dirty = 20        # 0-10000 credits
#vacuum_cost_limit = 200        # 1-10000 credits

# - Background Writer -

#bgwriter_delay = 200ms         # 10-10000ms between rounds
#bgwriter_lru_maxpages = 100        # 0-1000 max buffers written/round
#bgwriter_lru_multiplier = 2.0      # 0-10.0 multipler on buffers scanned/round

# - Asynchronous Behavior -

#effective_io_concurrency = 1       # 1-1000. 0 disables prefetching


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# WRITE AHEAD LOG
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Settings -

#wal_level = minimal            # minimal, archive, or hot_standby
                    # (change requires restart)
#fsync = on             # turns forced synchronization on or off
#synchronous_commit = on        # synchronization level; on, off, or local
#wal_sync_method = fsync        # the default is the first option
                    # supported by the operating system:
                    #   open_datasync
                    #   fdatasync (default on Linux)
                    #   fsync
                    #   fsync_writethrough
                    #   open_sync
#full_page_writes = on          # recover from partial page writes
#wal_buffers = -1           # min 32kB, -1 sets based on shared_buffers
                    # (change requires restart)
#wal_writer_delay = 200ms       # 1-10000 milliseconds

#commit_delay = 0           # range 0-100000, in microseconds
#commit_siblings = 5            # range 1-1000

# - Checkpoints -

#checkpoint_segments = 3        # in logfile segments, min 1, 16MB each
#checkpoint_timeout = 5min      # range 30s-1h
#checkpoint_completion_target = 0.5 # checkpoint target duration, 0.0 - 1.0
#checkpoint_warning = 30s       # 0 disables

# - Archiving -

#archive_mode = off     # allows archiving to be done
                # (change requires restart)
#archive_command = ''       # command to use to archive a logfile segment
#archive_timeout = 0        # force a logfile segment switch after this
                # number of seconds; 0 disables


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# REPLICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Master Server -

# These settings are ignored on a standby server

#max_wal_senders = 0        # max number of walsender processes
                # (change requires restart)
#wal_sender_delay = 1s      # walsender cycle time, 1-10000 milliseconds
#wal_keep_segments = 0      # in logfile segments, 16MB each; 0 disables
#vacuum_defer_cleanup_age = 0   # number of xacts by which cleanup is delayed
#replication_timeout = 60s  # in milliseconds; 0 disables
#synchronous_standby_names = '' # standby servers that provide sync rep
                # comma-separated list of application_name
                # from standby(s); '*' = all

# - Standby Servers -

# These settings are ignored on a master server

#hot_standby = off          # "on" allows queries during recovery
                    # (change requires restart)
#max_standby_archive_delay = 30s    # max delay before canceling queries
                    # when reading WAL from archive;
                    # -1 allows indefinite delay
#max_standby_streaming_delay = 30s  # max delay before canceling queries
                    # when reading streaming WAL;
                    # -1 allows indefinite delay
#wal_receiver_status_interval = 10s # send replies at least this often
                    # 0 disables
#hot_standby_feedback = off     # send info from standby to prevent
                    # query conflicts


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# QUERY TUNING
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Planner Method Configuration -

#enable_bitmapscan = on
#enable_hashagg = on
#enable_hashjoin = on
#enable_indexscan = on
#enable_material = on
#enable_mergejoin = on
#enable_nestloop = on
#enable_seqscan = on
#enable_sort = on
#enable_tidscan = on

# - Planner Cost Constants -

#seq_page_cost = 1.0            # measured on an arbitrary scale
#random_page_cost = 4.0         # same scale as above
#cpu_tuple_cost = 0.01          # same scale as above
#cpu_index_tuple_cost = 0.005       # same scale as above
#cpu_operator_cost = 0.0025     # same scale as above
#effective_cache_size = 128MB

# - Genetic Query Optimizer -

#geqo = on
#geqo_threshold = 12
#geqo_effort = 5            # range 1-10
#geqo_pool_size = 0         # selects default based on effort
#geqo_generations = 0           # selects default based on effort
#geqo_selection_bias = 2.0      # range 1.5-2.0
#geqo_seed = 0.0            # range 0.0-1.0

# - Other Planner Options -

#default_statistics_target = 100    # range 1-10000
#constraint_exclusion = partition   # on, off, or partition
#cursor_tuple_fraction = 0.1        # range 0.0-1.0
#from_collapse_limit = 8
#join_collapse_limit = 8        # 1 disables collapsing of explicit
                    # JOIN clauses


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ERROR REPORTING AND LOGGING
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Where to Log -

#log_destination = 'stderr'     # Valid values are combinations of
                    # stderr, csvlog, syslog, and eventlog,
                    # depending on platform.  csvlog
                    # requires logging_collector to be on.

# This is used when logging to stderr:
logging_collector = on          # Enable capturing of stderr and csvlog
                    # into log files. Required to be on for
                    # csvlogs.
                    # (change requires restart)

# These are only used if logging_collector is on:
#log_directory = 'pg_log'       # directory where log files are written,
                    # can be absolute or relative to PGDATA
log_filename = 'postgresql-%a.log'  # log file name pattern,
                    # can include strftime() escapes
#log_file_mode = 0600           # creation mode for log files,
                    # begin with 0 to use octal notation
log_truncate_on_rotation = on       # If on, an existing log file with the
                    # same name as the new log file will be
                    # truncated rather than appended to.
                    # But such truncation only occurs on
                    # time-driven rotation, not on restarts
                    # or size-driven rotation.  Default is
                    # off, meaning append to existing files
                    # in all cases.
log_rotation_age = 1d           # Automatic rotation of logfiles will
                    # happen after that time.  0 disables.
log_rotation_size = 0           # Automatic rotation of logfiles will
                    # happen after that much log output.
                    # 0 disables.

# These are relevant when logging to syslog:
#syslog_facility = 'LOCAL0'
#syslog_ident = 'postgres'

#silent_mode = off          # Run server silently.
                    # DO NOT USE without syslog or
                    # logging_collector
                    # (change requires restart)


# - When to Log -

#client_min_messages = notice       # values in order of decreasing detail:
                    #   debug5
                    #   debug4
                    #   debug3
                    #   debug2
                    #   debug1
                    #   log
                    #   notice
                    #   warning
                    #   error

#log_min_messages = warning     # values in order of decreasing detail:
                    #   debug5
                    #   debug4
                    #   debug3
                    #   debug2
                    #   debug1
                    #   info
                    #   notice
                    #   warning
                    #   error
                    #   log
                    #   fatal
                    #   panic

#log_min_error_statement = error    # values in order of decreasing detail:
                    #   debug5
                    #   debug4
                    #   debug3
                    #   debug2
                    #   debug1
                    #   info
                    #   notice
                    #   warning
                    #   error
                    #   log
                    #   fatal
                    #   panic (effectively off)

#log_min_duration_statement = -1    # -1 is disabled, 0 logs all statements
                    # and their durations, > 0 logs only
                    # statements running at least this number
                    # of milliseconds


# - What to Log -

#debug_print_parse = off
#debug_print_rewritten = off
#debug_print_plan = off
#debug_pretty_print = on
#log_checkpoints = off
#log_connections = off
#log_disconnections = off
#log_duration = off
#log_error_verbosity = default      # terse, default, or verbose messages
#log_hostname = off
#log_line_prefix = ''           # special values:
                    #   %a = application name
                    #   %u = user name
                    #   %d = database name
                    #   %r = remote host and port
                    #   %h = remote host
                    #   %p = process ID
                    #   %t = timestamp without milliseconds
                    #   %m = timestamp with milliseconds
                    #   %i = command tag
                    #   %e = SQL state
                    #   %c = session ID
                    #   %l = session line number
                    #   %s = session start timestamp
                    #   %v = virtual transaction ID
                    #   %x = transaction ID (0 if none)
                    #   %q = stop here in non-session
                    #        processes
                    #   %% = '%'
                    # e.g. '<%u%%%d> '
#log_lock_waits = off           # log lock waits >= deadlock_timeout
#log_statement = 'none'         # none, ddl, mod, all
#log_temp_files = -1            # log temporary files equal or larger
                    # than the specified size in kilobytes;
                    # -1 disables, 0 logs all temp files
#log_timezone = '(defaults to server environment setting)'


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# RUNTIME STATISTICS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Query/Index Statistics Collector -

#track_activities = on
#track_counts = on
#track_functions = none         # none, pl, all
#track_activity_query_size = 1024   # (change requires restart)
#update_process_title = on
#stats_temp_directory = 'pg_stat_tmp'


# - Statistics Monitoring -

#log_parser_stats = off
#log_planner_stats = off
#log_executor_stats = off
#log_statement_stats = off


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# AUTOVACUUM PARAMETERS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#autovacuum = on            # Enable autovacuum subprocess?  'on'
                    # requires track_counts to also be on.
#log_autovacuum_min_duration = -1   # -1 disables, 0 logs all actions and
                    # their durations, > 0 logs only
                    # actions running at least this number
                    # of milliseconds.
#autovacuum_max_workers = 3     # max number of autovacuum subprocesses
                    # (change requires restart)
#autovacuum_naptime = 1min      # time between autovacuum runs
#autovacuum_vacuum_threshold = 50   # min number of row updates before
                    # vacuum
#autovacuum_analyze_threshold = 50  # min number of row updates before
                    # analyze
#autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.2   # fraction of table size before vacuum
#autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.1  # fraction of table size before analyze
#autovacuum_freeze_max_age = 200000000  # maximum XID age before forced vacuum
                    # (change requires restart)
#autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay = 20ms    # default vacuum cost delay for
                    # autovacuum, in milliseconds;
                    # -1 means use vacuum_cost_delay
#autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit = -1  # default vacuum cost limit for
                    # autovacuum, -1 means use
                    # vacuum_cost_limit


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CLIENT CONNECTION DEFAULTS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Statement Behavior -

#search_path = '"$user",public'     # schema names
#default_tablespace = ''        # a tablespace name, '' uses the default
#temp_tablespaces = ''          # a list of tablespace names, '' uses
                    # only default tablespace
#check_function_bodies = on
#default_transaction_isolation = 'read committed'
#default_transaction_read_only = off
#default_transaction_deferrable = off
#session_replication_role = 'origin'
#statement_timeout = 0          # in milliseconds, 0 is disabled
#vacuum_freeze_min_age = 50000000
#vacuum_freeze_table_age = 150000000
#bytea_output = 'hex'           # hex, escape
#xmlbinary = 'base64'
#xmloption = 'content'

# - Locale and Formatting -

datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
#intervalstyle = 'postgres'
#timezone = '(defaults to server environment setting)'
#timezone_abbreviations = 'Default'     # Select the set of available time zone
                    # abbreviations.  Currently, there are
                    #   Default
                    #   Australia
                    #   India
                    # You can create your own file in
                    # share/timezonesets/.
#extra_float_digits = 0         # min -15, max 3
#client_encoding = sql_ascii        # actually, defaults to database
                    # encoding

# These settings are initialized by initdb, but they can be changed.
lc_messages = 'en_US.UTF-8'         # locale for system error message
                    # strings
lc_monetary = 'en_US.UTF-8'         # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'en_US.UTF-8'          # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'en_US.UTF-8'             # locale for time formatting

# default configuration for text search
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'

# - Other Defaults -

#dynamic_library_path = '$libdir'
#local_preload_libraries = ''


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# LOCK MANAGEMENT
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#deadlock_timeout = 1s
#max_locks_per_transaction = 64     # min 10
                    # (change requires restart)
# Note:  Each lock table slot uses ~270 bytes of shared memory, and there are
# max_locks_per_transaction * (max_connections + max_prepared_transactions)
# lock table slots.
#max_pred_locks_per_transaction = 64    # min 10
                    # (change requires restart)

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# VERSION/PLATFORM COMPATIBILITY
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Previous PostgreSQL Versions -

#array_nulls = on
#backslash_quote = safe_encoding    # on, off, or safe_encoding
#default_with_oids = off
#escape_string_warning = on
#lo_compat_privileges = off
#quote_all_identifiers = off
#sql_inheritance = on
#standard_conforming_strings = on
#synchronize_seqscans = on

# - Other Platforms and Clients -

#transform_null_equals = off


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ERROR HANDLING
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#exit_on_error = off                # terminate session on any error?
#restart_after_crash = on           # reinitialize after backend crash?


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CUSTOMIZED OPTIONS
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#custom_variable_classes = ''       # list of custom variable class names
```

Answer (score 75):

Run

```
sudo updatedb
```

followed by

```
locate postgresql.conf
```

Comment: I am not sure if `locate` can be relied upon because the file and also its directory may be accessible exclusively by postgres or the `products` user only.

Comment: @A-B-B "...accessible exclusively by *root*, postgres, or the `products` user only." Run it as root and it's reliable.

Comment: I would not trust the output of locate. Imagine these steps: Postgres version x is installed, updatedb reads the location of all files, postgres gets upgarded to version x+1. Now the cached data of locate is too old .... This is not reliable.

Comment: Not to mention that there could be all sorts of `postgresql.conf` files sticking around in example directories, e-book code samples, github downloads, etc...  This is really something to try *after* you've exhausted other possibilities.

Answer (score 14):

To get the location of the pg_hba.conf file, you can also query the database like

```
SHOW hba_file;
```

You should get something like

```
            hba_file             
---------------------------------
 /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf
(1 row)
```

Comment: atfer logging on as postgres or any super account as suggested in [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3603162/995072)

Answer (score 10):

If you have just installed it, it is possible that `locate` doesn't help. In that case, the service should be running and you can run

```
ps aux  | grep 'postgres *-D'
```

to see where the postgresql-master is loading the config files from.

Answer (score 8):

On Mac (Postgres installed using brew) :

```
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.3.3>bin/postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres/
```

Answer (score 8):

On Mac OS X:

```
sudo find / -name postgresql.conf
```

You can find other conf files by the following command:

```
sudo find / -name pg\*.conf
```

Note: See usage using man:

```
man find
```

Answer (score 8):

Print pg_hba.conf file location:

```
su - postgres -c "psql -t -P format=unaligned -c 'show hba_file';"
```

Print postgresql.conf file location:

```
su - postgres -c "psql -t -P format=unaligned -c 'SHOW config_file';"
```

Answer (score 7):

**30-07-2019**

In Windows 10 pro:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\data
```

Comment: For me it was at `C:\temp\PostgreSQL_data`.

Answer (score 6):

On Fedora 20

```
$ cd /var/lib/pgsql/data
$ ls -ltr *.conf

-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 20453 Jan 18 23:22 postgresql.conf
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres  1636 Jan 18 23:22 pg_ident.conf
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres  4476 Jan 18 23:22 pg_hba.conf
```

Answer (score 6):

For CentOS 6 and 7 and postgresql 9.2 (and below, I suppose, possibly Fedora and Redhat as well):

`/var/lib/pgsql/data`

For CentOS 6 and 7 postgresql 9.3 or 9.4 (and above, I suppose):

```
/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data
/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data
```

For Ubuntu 14 and postgresql 9.3:

`/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf`

Answer (score 5):

The answer may be that you have not initialized the database yet.   After installing postgres, but before initializing the database, the postgres*.sql files will be absent.   After initializing the database the postgres*.sql files will appear.  (Centos 6, Postgres 9.3 demonstrated here)

```
[root@localhost /]# yum -y install postgresql93 postgresql93-server 
[root@localhost /]# ls /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/
[root@localhost /]#
[root@localhost /]# service postgresql-9.3 initdb
Initializing database:                                     [  OK  ]
[root@localhost /]# ls /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data/
base         pg_ident.conf  pg_serial     pg_subtrans  pg_xlog
global       pg_log         pg_snapshots  pg_tblspc    postgresql.conf
pg_clog      pg_multixact   pg_stat       pg_twophase
pg_hba.conf  pg_notify      pg_stat_tmp   PG_VERSION
[root@localhost /]#
```

Answer (score 4):

As I don't have access to postgres account (so can't run `SHOW config_file`) and my postgres is installed on Windows, none of the answers helped me, so I'm sharing my file location for future Windows readers:

`C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\data`

Comment: This has changed with postgresql 10. I'll update this comment when I find it

Answer (score 4):

Besides [the direct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3603162/1468388), you will probably want to check out [the docs about Postgres config file locations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-file-locations.html).

In most cases: under `$PGDATA`, which is normally `/var/lib/postgresql/data` or something similar (at least it's the default path if you use [Docker images](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/)).

Answer (score 4):

If you have the postgres in a docker container, probably you are binding the .conf file, to find the .conf file you are using outside the docker, run  `docker inspect postgres11` or the postgres container name or id. That command returns a json, look for somethig like

```
"HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/home/my_user/postgres11/:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
            ]
```

If you execute `SHOW config_file;` and the result is in `/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf` then you know the .conf file outside is in `/home/my_user/postgres11/postgresql.conf`, or the resulted in the property "Binds"

Answer (score 3):

I like this thread because it documents the default locations for various postgresql.conf files on various architectures...

**However**, I've also gotten in trouble by relying on those defaults on installations where they have specified alternate locations. One way to find out where a particular config file is by querying the database directly:

`select * from pg_settings where name='config_file'`

Drop the `where` clause to see all the settings, which can also be illuminating because it shows where data directories, pg_hba.conf, etc. are.

Answer (score 3):

For Debian 9 I found mine using Franke Heikens answer - $ /etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf

Answer (score 2):

nantha=# SHOW config_file;

### config_file

/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
(1 row)

nantha=# SHOW hba_file;

### hba_file

/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_hba.conf
(1 row)

Answer (score 2):

Win7, version 10 location:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\postgresql.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

I located it here:

```
/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/postgresql.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

In CentOS 7 with PostgreSQL 9.4 it's in the following directory:

```
/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data
```

I can see it when I'm logged in as root.

Answer (score 1):

on MacOS Mojave where I used `brew install postgresql` to install, I found it here

`/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf`

I got this using the following sql command cited in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3603162/2668545) response here:

`psql -U postgres -c 'SHOW config_file'`

Answer (score 1):

For ubuntu 18/20, run the following command to locate your postgresql.conf file:

```
locate postgresql.conf
```

If locate is missing in your linux then run `sudo apt-get install locate` to install locate first.

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu, you can find

```
/etc/postgresql/11/main/pg_hba.conf

// after change restart it otherwise it won't be work

service postgresql restart
```

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu:
It's in `Other Locations` tab
path : /etc/postgresql/16/main

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you followed the white paper put out by Amazon for installing Postgresql on AWS, which included creating a /data/ directory on a filesystem mounted on a separate EBS volume, then your postgresql.conf file is in /data/

From which I conclude the file is created during initialisation of the data directory, and resides in the root of the data dir. For a default install this appears to be /var/lib/pgsql/data, but not if you moved the data dir

Answer (score -1):

My installation is not default, but you can go to directory the Postgres and find subdirectory \Data.

**Configuration Files**
C:\Postgres\Data\postgresql.conf
C:\Postgres\Data\pg_hba.conf

Comment: OS in question is Linux.

Answer (score -1):

On linux default location is:

```
cd /etc/postgresql/12/main/
```

12-version
version might be vary according to installed version

Answer (score -2):

2022-4-25 update:

Location: `/Library/PostgreSQL/14/data/postgresql.conf`

System: `MacOS Monterey`

Just for anyone who is looking for this path...

Comment: this is for installation using .dmg file. and if you are using a different version change the number 14 in the path to your version