# Where are my postgresql *.conf files in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-12.04

I need to find the path to the postgresql.conf file in Ubuntu 12.04. I have seen [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602450/where-are-my-postgres-conf-files) but perhaps since my o/s is Ubuntu 12.04, those answers have not worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found them in /etc/postgresql/9.1/main