# View Rails database log in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I can view my production database log on Heroku by running `heroku logs -p postgres -t` from my development machine. How can I do this to my development database?

Just trying to debug some rails commands that skip Rails and go direct to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're on a Mac and that you installed Postgres via Homebrew, you can view the local Postgres logs in real time on your development machine by running the following command:

```
tail -f /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log
```

Comment: Thanks. I am running Ubuntu also also with PGAdminIII (3) so it was located at my `/home/username/pgadmin.log'. I also had to change the postgresql.conf file as per user3118220 comments below. And also ran `SHOW config_file;` as an SQL command to find the location of my postgresql.conf file. Cheers all. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602450/where-are-my-postgres-conf-files

Answer (score 2):

You would have to enable logging of all SQL executed by PostgreSQL

In your `data/postgresql.conf` file, change the log_statement setting to `'all'`.

[Error Reporting and Logging - log_statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT)

`tail -f fil_path` that will show run time updation of file, so You can check with the help of it

```
tail -f /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log
```