# How to connect postgresql database on remote server rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, centos

I'm trying to connect to a remote server from my local machine. Here's how my database.yml file looks like:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: db_name
  username: mac
  password: mac
  host: 178.XXX.XXX.XXX
  port: 5432
  pool: 10
  timeout: 5000
```

I edited pg_hba.conf to take my ip address:

```
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all            35.XXX.XX.XX/32          trust

# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Remote server is hosted on `AWS` with `centos 6` AMI. Below inbound rules are added in it's security group.
[image]

But I keep getting below error:

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "<HOST NAME>" (178.XXX.XXX.XXX) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

For logs checked `/var/lib/pgsql/9.6/data/pg_log`, however no logs are being created.

Running netstat -ntlp tells that server is listening on 5432 port
[image]

Am I missing something or doing something wrong here?
please help

Comment: First, can you confirm if the Postgres process is running on the remote server?

Comment: yes it's running

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer from yesterday. There is a procedure how find a problem with connecting to the remote PostgreSQL database:

[Remote PostgreSQL connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50049463/remote-postgresql-connection-with-pgadmin)

The error you have posted is not related to Ruby on rails. It is standard problem with wrong PostgreSQL settings. First try psql which should show the same error as you posted

Write a comment if you will have a problem. I bet that the problem is because you forgot set `listen_address"'*'` in `postgresql.conf` because you don't mention this in the answer.

Comment: Hi Bulva, I added listen_address as well and  followed your answer, but i still have the same connection error.

Comment: So try restart PostgreSQL service and check the log in /var/logs/syslog or /var/logs/posgresql. Maybe did you try set pg_hba.conf like on the other answer? Maybe you made a mistake in your ip

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your support, it was a firewall issue. I disabled the firewall and it worked. :)

Comment: Ok. So don't forget you shouldn't disable firewall for all ports. It is better to open in/out port for posgresql