# Unable to connect from local psql to postgresql using ip address

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to connect from a `psql` session to a locally running `postgresql`:

```
psql -h 192.168.195.84 -d aact_bac
```

The `pg_hba.conf` entry is:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0                   md5
host    all             all             192.168.195.84/0            md5
```

Here is the result:

```
psql: FATAL:  psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "192.168.195.84", 
user "pointr", database "aact_back", SSL o for host "192.168.195.84", 
user "pointr", database "aact_back", SSL o
```

What is missing here?

**Update** The following had been done several times - after each attempt for change in `pg_hba.conf`:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

It was verified that the pg server had been restarted by seeing the launch time from `ps -ef | grep postgres`.

Comment: You do not specify the mask length `192.168.195.84/32`. Also dont forget to reload.

Comment: So "local" does not mean "localhost"?

Comment: Assuming postgresql 10 or newer, can you check the result of `select * from pg_hba_file_rules`

Answer (score 0):

Here is best answer for you, if it works, this is duplicate answer.
If you don't leave comment. :D

I think this is you missed.

```
# content in pg_hba.conf

# IPv4 local connections:
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

[Remote PostgreSQL connection with pgAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50049463/remote-postgresql-connection-with-pgadmin)

Comment: thanks - I actually already had that entry: will add to the question