# Cannot change datestyle intellij IDE

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to change datestyle from 'ISO, MDA' to 'ISO, DMA'. I execute this command in intellij postegresql console :

```
SET datestyle = "ISO, DMY";
```

It changes the  datestyle but temporary; when trying to check it in another terminal it returns to 'ISO, MDA'

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the datestyle change permanent, add it to the `postgresql.conf` file:

```
 datestyle = 'iso, dmy'
```

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602450/where-are-my-postgres-conf-files) if you need to locate the conf file.

Comment: Orks as a charm. Thank you