# postgresql@10-main.service failed to load

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I have been racking my brain on this issue, and probably have tried every possible solution ( fix, purge, reinstall), but postgresql doesn't start

```
rupin@linuxbox:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
[sudo] password for rupin: 


Restarting PostgreSQL 10 database server 
Failed to issue method call: Unit postgresql@10-main.service failed to load: No such file or directory. See system logs and 'systemctl status postgresql@10-main.service' for details.
```

The Log file is empty. There is no postmaster.pid file that could be to blame.

My Ubuntu Laptop crashed and the DB was active when the system crashed.

Can someone advise what I can do to fix this issue and start the server again?

**Update **

```
rupin@linuxbox:~$ systemctl status postgresql@10-main.service
Failed to issue method call: No such interface 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties' on object at path /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/postgresql_4010_2dmain_2eservice
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Become OS user `postgres`.

Try to start PostgreSQL with

```
pg_ctl start -D /etc/postgres/10/main
```

(Use the path where `postgresql.conf` resides.)

Then you will see the error and you will know what to do about it.

Comment: I cant seem to find that config file. I used locate postgresql.conf according to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602450/where-are-my-postgres-conf-files but the file is empty at location /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/postgresql.conf

Comment: I have added some more information to my original question. I also looked at https://askubuntu.com/questions/873091/postgresql-fails-to-reinstall-after-upgrading-ubuntu-12-04-to-14-04 and I dont see a file at path /usr/share/postgresql-common/init.d-functions.

Comment: Then you probably removed your database.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions of the answer from https://askubuntu.com/questions/873091/postgresql-fails-to-reinstall-after-upgrading-ubuntu-12-04-to-14-04

I ended up removing systemd

```
sudo apt-get purge systemd && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

And I was able to reinstall postgres. Unfortunately, I lost my data/cant trace it. It is okay for me, because it is my local DB