# Connect to a older Postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11, postgresql-12

I have PostgreSQL installed in my Linux machine, I'm following a old YT tutorial for work and the instructor is using PostgreSQL 11. I have already used the following command:

```
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-11
```

To install PostgreSQL 11 in my machine, how do I connect to this specific version and not version 12?

Comment: Just use 12. It can do anything 11 can, identically in most cases. I would doubt there is anything in your tutorial will have any change. If you have issues just post a question and indicate the difference in Postgres version. BTW I use v12 locally yet deploy to v9.5 and v10. Have never had a problem.

Comment: TypeORM had no support for Postgress 12, I was already using Postgress 12 until now but I recently ran into major problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Postgress configuration files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602450/where-are-my-postgres-conf-files) are located at:

```
/etc/postgresql/##/main/postgresql.conf
```

Use your favorite code editor and navigate to the **CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION** this will reveal at which port the Postgress database is listening.
Connect to you desired version using the -p flag. For me Postgres 11 is using port 5433 and Postgres 12 is using 5432.

```
psql -h 5433 postgress
```

Check your version using

```sql
SHOW version();
```

Expected output

```
                                                          version                                                           
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 11.9 (Ubuntu 11.9-1.pgdg20.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd installed version is probably running on port 5433 rather than 5432.
But rather than guessing, you can run `pg_lsclusters` and see.  Then specify that port number whereever you need to connect.