# Postgres doesn't ask for a password even though I required one when I created user

Tags: postgresql

I have already changed all the 'trust' values in pg_hba.conf to 'md5', restarted and reloaded postgres, but even though I've specified that my user requires a password, postgres does not require a password when I log in using: `psql -U test -d financestracker`.  What else could I be missing?

Comment: Is it already set up in the password file?  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/libpq-pgpass.html

Comment: `PGPASSWORD` env variable, `.pgpass` file, more than one instance of PG running, which means more than one pg_hba.conf file

Comment: thank you @clamp - how can I check these things?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602450/where-are-my-postgres-conf-files (`SHOW hba_file;` when logged in as postgres) and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/libpq-envars.html also the link, @Hambone showed.

Comment: I'm looking these over, but how could i set the env variable or .pgpass file in order to require password?  I can't find an answer to that here.

Comment: You can't set them to require a password. But if they have been set accidentally, you won't need a password, because it is provided automatically.

Comment: I see, thanks.  My question is that I want postgres to require a password for users that have a password specified for them.  How can I do this?  Right now I can log in as any user and never need a password.

Comment: @Hambone I don't think I'm using the pgpass file.  I can't find an instance of it anywhere.  Any other possibilities?

Comment: Please add `pg_hba.conf` to the question.

Comment: Since you can log in, check `select * from pg_hba_file_rules` to make sure it is set how you want.

Comment: Can you humor me and post your entire pg_hba.conf file?

Comment: I actually think I have it working correctly now, but I would still be interested to hear if I got this right.  Too much text to paste in here so check it out here:
https://pastebin.com/raw/m3mXTMVy