# Postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file. After "brew install postgresql"

Tags: postgresql, macos, homebrew

I have installed PostgreSQL on MacOS Big Sur version 11.3 with brew install postgresql.

When I run the `postgres` command I get this error

```
postgres does not know where to find the server configuration file.`
You must specify the --config-file or -D invocation option or set the PGDATA environment variable.
```

Where do I find the config file?

Comment: Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602450/where-are-my-postgres-conf-files

Answer (score 5):

Checking from the package formula `postgresql.rb` by `brew cat postgresql`, the datadir is `${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/var/postgres`. (`HOMEBREW_PREFIX` is not an exported env var, it's used by homebrew internally)

- `/usr/local/var/postgres` on x86 Mac
- `/opt/homebrew/var/postgres` on M1 Mac

This dir should be created automatically during `brew install postgresql`.

BTW, the canonical way to start psql with Homebrew should be `brew services start postgresql`, which uses `launchd` on macOS to manage services. (For newbie on macOS, `launchd` could be seen as a `systemd` alternative on macOS.)

Run `brew info postgresql` and some additional tips is displayed in the `Caveats` part of the output.

```
❯ brew info postgresql
postgresql: stable 13.3 (bottled), HEAD
Object-relational database system
https://www.postgresql.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/13.3 (3,225 files, 38.8MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2021-05-14 at 09:37:24
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/postgresql.rb
License: PostgreSQL
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔
Required: icu4c ✔, krb5 ✔, openssl@1.1 ✔, readline ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
        Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
To migrate existing data from a previous major version of PostgreSQL run:
  brew postgresql-upgrade-database

This formula has created a default database cluster with:
  initdb --locale=C -E UTF-8 /usr/local/var/postgres
For more details, read:
  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-initdb.html

To have launchd start postgresql now and restart at login:
  brew services start postgresql
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
```

Comment: user commands 
To start: `pg_ctl -D /opt/homebrew/var/postgres start` 
To stop: `pg_ctl -D /opt/homebrew/var/postgres stop`

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac (Big Sur), it's located at `/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf`. The command I use to start the server is:

`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start`

Comment: I've tried this and I get:

pg_ctl: directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" does not exist