# Can I reset the Postgres settings file to default in Docker? How?

Tags: postgresql, docker, reset, postgresql.conf

Forgive me if this is a lame question but I'm pretty new in this and a bit lost. Started a PostgreSQL 16 server on Docker yesterday (fresh and clean install, never used these before). Today I wanted to debug a procedure and messed with the postgresql.conf file (added a line). After restarting the server it never came up again, the log says that the .conf file contains syntax errors. However I'm not able to reach the file any more as it was only at its location when the server was running. How can I get back to the default state (or edit the file) and get the server running?
Thanks.
If it can be fixed the bonus question will be the working solution on debugging...
I've used DBeaver to make the procedure and saved it but learned that it lacks this option. Then downloaded pgAdmin 4 (via Docker and also the windows-version) but so far I couldn't reach the user interface of any of them.

Comment: Stop the container, remove the container, restart the container. If you are not working with volume mounts, this will give you a fresh postgres container.

Comment: I'd rather keep the work of the last day, and it's only in that container. Will it remain there afterwards?

Comment: Are you using a volume? If so: possibly. If not: no. If the container still runs (and only the postgres process stopped), you can try to get an interactive shell into the container (`docker exec -it <container-id> /bin/bash`).

Comment: "I'm not able to reach the file any more as it was only at its location when the server was running" IF postgres is still complaining about it, the file must still be read by postgres.  You can create a new postgres container [just to find the config file location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3603162/1726083) , then `docker cp` that file out of the original container, fix it, and `docker cp` it back in.

Comment: In Docker, if I click on Volumes, there is a volume for the postgres server in use. Does this mean I'm using a volume? (I can literally feel the lameness radiating from me, beware.) In Containers there is another instance of the server saying "exited".  The ... -it ... command gave an error saying the container is not running.

Comment: When the server is running I know the location of the file (\var\lib\postgresql\data), but when it's stopped the file structure is different and that directory seems empty. The file must be stored somewhere of course but the commands in the linked topic doesn't work for me (probably because I'm on windows, or because the server is off).

Comment: I've found an Inspect option at the container and there's a section "Mounts" where the "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/blahblah/_data", and
"Destination": "/var/lib/postgresql/data" makes sense. The problem is that I can't see this _data folder at all. I've installed the Backup extension of Docker and made a copy of the volume. I'll try to restore it on another pg-server if I can.

Comment: The backup transferred the error and prevented the new server from starting. But I could open the backup (tar.zst archive) and found the config file, edited, packed back and restored, now it's up and running :) thanks for the help guys. Now for the 2nd part: how do I debug a procedure here?