# pghero on PostgresApp pg_stat_statements must be loaded via shared_preload_libraries

Tags: postgresql, rails-postgresql

I have this error

```
  PG::ObjectNotInPrerequisiteState: ERROR:  pg_stat_statements must be loaded via shared_preload_libraries
```

on localhost. Using osx (10.9.5), PostgresApp 9.3.1.0 and pghero gem

Going to postgresql.conf located in `~/Library/Application Support/Postgres93/var`
I have this in the top of the file

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements'
pg_stat_statements.track = all
```

So, either this is the correct postgresql.conf, or something in my setup is broken..

Any ideas?

Comment: You can check which config file your server is using through `show config_file;`

Comment: that gives me `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/data/postgresql.conf` which doesn't exist...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that command displayed my mistake. I've been changing the wrong conf file.

Answer (score 63):

You have to restart the Postgresql Server in order to load the shared library and afterwards execute

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_stat_statements;
```

in the database you want to monitor.

Additionally you will have to edit the following line in `postgresql.conf`

```
shared_preload_libraries = ''
```

To

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements'
```

A restart of the PSQL service is required.

Comment: This duplicates the answer of @compyutech, doesn't it?

Comment: Wanted to state clearly that a restart is necessary before one can use the extension and no one said that before. otherwise yes, its duplicate if that not an important information

Comment: just creating the extension without editing shared_preload_libraries in postgresql.conf didn't work for me, that's why it's not duplicate

Answer (score 3):

Create extension by executing following query

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_stat_statements
```

Comment: This error occurs AFTER the extension has already been created...

Answer (score 1):

if you're using docker image you have two options:

[manually modify config file:](https://gist.github.com/lfittl/1b0671ac07b33521ea35fcd22b0120f5?permalink_comment_id=3412990#gistcomment-3412990)

```
docker cp postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf postgresql.conf
vi postgresql.conf
docker cp postgresql.conf postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
docker restart postgres
```

[add to startup command using docker/docker compose:](https://gist.github.com/lfittl/1b0671ac07b33521ea35fcd22b0120f5?permalink_comment_id=3142997#gistcomment-3142997)

```
command: postgres -c shared_preload_libraries=pg_stat_statements -c pg_stat_statements.track=all
```