# How to add extension pg_stat extension to postgres bitnami helm chart?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes-helm, helm3, pg-stat-statements

I have following **Chart.yaml**

```
dependencies:
- name: postgresql
  version: 11.6.7
  repository: "@bitnami"
  condition: postgresql.enabled
```

**values.yaml**:

```
postgresql:
  auth:
    database: ...
    password: ...
    postgresPassword: ...
  metrics:
    ...
    enabled: true
    serviceMonitor:
      enabled: true      
  ...
  primary:
    initdb:
      scriptsConfigMap: "postgres-init-scripts-config"
```

And inside the config I have following:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_stat_statements;
```

I start my appplication and then I try to run following query:

I hasn't found answer here also: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/2067

```
select * from pg_stat_statements;
```

and restart is:

```
ERROR:  pg_stat_statements must be loaded via shared_preload_libraries
SQL state: 55000
```

I have read this topic: [pghero on PostgresApp pg_stat_statements must be loaded via shared_preload_libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28147037/pghero-on-postgresapp-pg-stat-statements-must-be-loaded-via-shared-preload-libra)

And based on other topics from SO looks ike I need to restart postgres. But I don't know how can I acheve it.

Also this topic hasn't given me the answer how to enable extension properly in helm chart.

**P.S.** In my case I create database inside postgres-init-scripts-config and I need to have extension pg_stat_statements enabled for that database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix after I've added:

```
postgresql
  metrics
    primary:
      extendedConfiguration: |
        shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements' # (change requires restart)
        pg_stat_statements.max = 10000
        pg_stat_statements.track = all
```