# How to use the @> 'contains' operator with Dapper ORM

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper

Using the Dapper ORM I'm constructing the following query to get a specific order from my PostgreSQL datastore:

```
string.Format("SELECT * FROM OrderTable WHERE orderjson @> {0}",
    "'{\"Lines\":[{\"SKUID\":\"@SkuId\"}]}'");
```

Passing `123456-0` into the paramater `@SkuId` this construction should result into the following query

```
SELECT * FROM ordertable WHERE orderjson @> '{"Lines":[{"SKUID":"123456-0"}]}'
```

However Dapper seems to have some trouble with the `@>` contains operator, as the query always returns no results.

How do I use this `@>` operator with Dapper?

### Update

I updated my construction to the following:

```
$@"
    SELECT * FROM ordertable
    WHERE orderjson @> '{{""Lines"":[{{""SKUID"": ""@SkuId"" }}]}}'
";
```

Dapper seems to ignore the paramter `@SkuId` as my query looks like

```
SELECT * FROM ordertable
WHERE orderjson @> '{"Lines":[{"SKUID": "@SkuId" }]}'
```

Comment: You should be able to parameterize the query. Does the sql work in the pgsql console?

Comment: Yes, running the query within pgAdmin gives me 1 result

Comment: Doesn't Dapper only do something special with a query when it uses curly braces? That may be where the problem is?

Comment: Try profiling to see exactly what is being passed to your DB.

Comment: @juharr any recommendation for a good/simple profiler for this case?

Comment: @DavidG maybe, can't find anything yet regarding this but will look further on that as well

Comment: Note that Dapper is open source, so you can check it out to see what might be happening.  As for profilers I just use the one that comes with SQL Server.

Comment: [PostgreSQL equivalent of SQL Server profiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430380/is-there-a-postgresql-equivalent-of-sql-server-profiler)

Comment: Try remove quotes around `@SkuId`.

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov that makes no difference unfortunately, I _think_ dapper is confused because of the `@>` operator

Comment: This issue on gitbub might be useful https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/575. Try to prepare entire json as a parameter but beware of sql injection.

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov this is useful

Comment: Hacky workaround - dapper just wants to see the parameter name in the sql; if the member name is `foo`, you can include a SQL comment of `/* @foo */` and the member will be sent...

Answer (score 1):

See also this [Github issue](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/575) which might be useful as well.

We end up splitting into two statements:

```
SkuLineJson = $@"{{""Lines"":[{{""SKUID"": ""{object.SkuId}""}}]}}"
```

And use this variable in our sql statement construction:

```
$@" SELECT * FROM ordertable 
    WHERE orderjson @> json_in(@SkuLineJson::cstring)::jsonb
";
```